# Mathematically applying regularisation to logistic regression to reduce over fitting

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification

I recently was introduced to the concept of regularisation to reduce the process of overfitting in logistic regression were the curve fits too perfectly to a point where our non linear line does a very bad job at generalising our data.

The way we did this we edited the cost function actually;

Hypothesis function -> H(Q) = Q0 + Q1 x X1 + Q2 x X2 + Q3 x X3.....

Cost function -> 
[image: Cost Function of logistic regression]

All we did was multiply values to these parameters in order to reduce them apparently;

1000Q4 + 1000Q4 ....

[image: After adding regularisation calculation to cost function !]

Now my question here, how is this managing to reduce the size of the parameters ( Regularisation ), since we are multiplying 1000 or any big number to the parameters, isn't it actually increasing the value of the parameters Q3, Q4... etc ?

Comment: your minimizing the function so, since they are being multiplied by large numbers, the values of the $\theta_{i}$ are going to tend to be smaller ( so that the function is minimized )  and they correspond to the $Q_{i}$ in your earlier statement.